# jQuery UI Resizable with overflow-y

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I have a div which is resizable but now I have the problem that there is a y-scrollbar. The problem is that this scrollbar isn't necessary, because all content is visible.

**Image**

[image: scrollbar]

**HTML**

```
<script>$( "#pc_test" ).resizable({handles: \'n, s\'});</script>
<div id="panel_test">
    <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Test</div>
    <div id="pc_test" class="panelcontent ui-resizable" style="font-size: 14px;">
    Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panelheadbar { padding: 5px; font-weight: bold; color: #000; height: auto; }
.pgrau { background-color: #ccc; }
.panelcontent { overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;padding: 10px; background-color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

How can I fix this, that there is only a scrollbar when it's needed?

**Edit: I want a scrollbar if the user resized it too much.**

**Edit 2: here there should be a scrollbar**
[image]

**Edit3: The result should look like this**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

## A Good Manners Answer

The problem might be on the `<div>` hierarchy. Because when you have one `<div>` inside another, the first `<div>` will need to be set as `relative` and the sequence set of `<div>` need to be set to `absolute` position.

## HTML

The HTML will stay as it is.

```
<script>$( "#pc_test" ).resizable({handles: \'n, s\'});</script>
<div id="panel_test">
    <div class="panelheadbar pgrau">Test</div>
    <div id="pc_test" class="panelcontent ui-resizable" style="font-size: 14px;">
    Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>Test<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

That way you should have on CSS:

```
.panelheadbar {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    height: auto;
}

.pgrau {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.panelcontent {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

That way it should work.

Comment: So `<div id="panel_test">` has to be relative and the others absolute?

Comment: I added a second image to my question. With your solution I get this response but in that case there should be a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

## A Simple Answer

You just need to change `overflow: auto;` to `overflow: hidden;` property:

```
.panelheadbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    height: auto;
}

.pgrau {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.panelcontent {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

The overflow property specifies what to do if the content of an element exceeds the size of the element's box.

Comment: Oh sry, at this position should stand "overflow-y; auto;", because I want to have a scrollbar when you resized it to much.

Comment: Nope because I want a scrollbar, but not if it's not needed. My problem is that there is a scrollbar even if there is enough height.

Comment: Try it on `.panelheadbar` and then tell me if it works please.

Comment: `.panelheadbar` with `overflow:hidden` and `.panelcontent` with `overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;` didn't work

Comment: So please give us more from your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

## Box Re-size Problem Answer

For the second problem you will need to use `height: auto;` in the `.panelcontent` field:

```
.panelheadbar {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    height: auto;
}

.pgrau {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.panelcontent {
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

The options for `overflow` are:

`overflow:  visible | hidden | scroll | auto | inherit`

As you can see on the description of CSS overflow Property:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

I recommend you as well to watch this link:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

Comment: I added a picture how the result should look like (edit 3)

Comment: Try to change `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;` on the `.panelcontent` and see how it works please.

Comment: With that solution I get no scrollbar at all.

Comment: If you want to keep the scroll and have on the same time space enough for the text box you can easily add more `height` and `width`.

Comment: But the problem is, even if I have enough height for the text, the scrollbar is still there. And in this case the scrollbar should be hidden

Comment: So you just need to make it `auto` or other option you might want:

`overflow: visible|hidden|scroll|auto|initial|inherit;`

Comment: Isn't `overflow: auto` the correct choice when I want a scrollbar only if it's needed?
And I think the height-variable comes from the ui-resizable.

Comment: Yes it is, like you said.